# How to do calculation like sum and others with SQL statement in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, winrt-xaml

I want to add up all LineAmount where Sid = 1, How to do it in SQLite?

What need to do in SQL statement?

```
await db.QueryAsync<Transaction>("Select * From Transaction Where Sid =1");

class TransactionLine
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int TId { get; set; }

    public int Sid { get; set; }
    public string No { get; set; }    
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal LineDisPerc { get; set; }
    public decimal LineDiscAmt { get; set; }
    public decimal LineAmount { get; set; }

     public decimal FinalAmount { get; set; }

 }
```

---- Update:

```
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
{
    var Orders = db.Query<TransactionLine>("Select *, Sum(FinalAmount) From TransactionLine where Sid ==" + OrderId);

    foreach (var lineTrans in Orders)
    {
        txtBlkAMT.Text = lineTrans.Amount.ToString();
    }          
}
```

Problem:

- If I have 3 line of order, it does not sum up correctly.

----- Update 2.

This works:

But is there any short cut using Sum() or other function in SQL-statement?

decimal LineTTL = 0;
     decimal LineAmt = 0;
     int Count =0;

```
var Orders = db.Query<TransactionLine>("Select * From TransactionLine where SId ==" + OrderId);                 

    foreach (var lineTrans in Orders)
     {

       LineAmt = lineTrans.Amount;

       LineTTL = LineTTL + LineAmt;

      TTLAmt = LineTTL;


      }
```

Comment: What is `TransactionLine`? What do you mean with "not correctly"?

Comment: I have updated my solution. Is there any function like Sum() to use in Sql-statement for Sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a SUM function:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM TransactionLine WHERE SId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Sum(FinalAmount) AS Amount FROM TransactionLine WHERE Sid = 1
```

PS Using "Transaction" as a table name is not a good idea (reserved word).

Answer (score -1):

sqlite> SELECT NAME, SUM(SALARY) FROM COMPANY GROUP BY NAME;

Comment: I use this "Select *, Sum(FinalAmount)From TransactionLine where Sid ==", but it does not Sum up correctly as my above update.

Comment: This does not answer the question.